# How to update one filed in elsaticsearch document by Java API using Script?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I wanna update one filed in elasticSearch. I have the id of the document and new value. I don't know how to write a script for it. how do I mention the docs Id? I wrote as below but doesn't work. studentId is the filed should have changed and the result is the new value

```
            UpdateResponse response = dataTransportClient.prepareUpdate(
            AppSettings.ELASTIC_SERVICE_NAME,
            AppSettings.ELASTIC_DB_NAME,
            studentId)
            .setScript(
                    new Script(
                            ScriptType.INLINE,
                            "painless",
                            "ctx._source.studentId="+result,
                             Collections.emptyMap()
                    )
            )
            .setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.NONE)
            .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with change it as below :

```
        UpdateResponse response = dataTransportClient.prepareUpdate(
        AppSettings.ELASTIC_SERVICE_NAME,
        AppSettings.ELASTIC_DB_NAME,
        studentId)
           .setScript(
                new Script(
                        ScriptType.INLINE,
                        "painless",
                        "ctx._source.response =" + (JsonUtil.getJson(result)),
                         Collections.emptyMap()
                          )
                     )
        .setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.NONE)
        .get();
```